# How to test call back refs with Enzyme and Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test addEventListener/RemoveEventListener for an Element.

```
 class Image extends PureComponent {

  state = {
    isLoaded: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.src) return;
    this.imageToLoad = document.createElement('img');
    this.imageToLoad.addEventListener('load', this.loadImage);
    this.imageToLoad.src = this.props.src;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (!this.imageToLoad) return;
    this.imageToLoad.removeEventListener('load', this.loadImage);
  }

  loadImage = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true }, () => {
      this.myimg.src = this.imageToLoad.src;
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { className, src, alt } = this.props;
    const { isLoaded } = this.state;
    if (isLoaded === false || !src) return '';
    return (
      <img
        className={className}
        ref={img => (this.myimg = img)}
        src={src}
        alt={alt}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Test code:-

```
  it('should add event listener on mount', () => {
    const elementMock = { addEventListener: jest.fn() };
    jest.spyOn(Image.prototype, 'myimg').mockImplementation(() => elementMock);
    expect(elementMock.addEventListener).toBeCalledWith('load', expect.any(Function), false);
  });
```

But it is not working as expected.